# Sending postMessage via iframe and open.window in Safari

Tags: iframe, safari, window.open, postmessage

I'm exchanging data between two domains with iframe and postMessage, receiver page is saving data in localStorage. There is only one problem with Safari browser. Local storage don't want to sync between open tabs if I send data via iframe. I was trying to use window.open and then send data, but on production new window don't want to open. On testing environment it was working.

Only solution I did think of is to allow in preferences to open popup windows. Second thing was to set also in preferences "Cookies and website data" to "Always allow". But I want to not force user to change settings.

Anybody can help me with this problem, to sync localStorage data between tabs in Safari without forcing user to change settings in browser???

Thank's in advance,
Dominik